# Многопоточность curl , помогите пожалуйста переделать скрипт, уж очень долго идет загрузка

Tags: php, многопоточность, curl

Здравствуйте) кто может научить , подсказать , поставить на путь истинный как говорится... почитал , посмотрел, подумал и ничего не надумал на счет curl_multi.. не могу понять как переделать то что есть )

Вот сам скипт мой, списком заносятся около 120 ников, которые далее преобазуются в ссылку, путем добавления ника в конец ссылки... и обработка по каждому значению..
Если добавлять 5-6 то допустимое время ожидания, а вот когда их много очень и очень медленно всё... очень прошу помощи...

```
        <?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $message = $_POST['message'];


$message = strip_tags($message);
$message = preg_split("/[?[][\w]{1,2}]/", $message);
$message =  preg_replace('/ {2}/','',$message);



function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$ups = "&noredir=9462fa1c293699b04eb15e8b8d84b9ba";
//$nick_names = ['Пишите.. не сомнивайтесь, будьте первыми )) ']; // пример произвольного массива ник-неймов
$length = count($message);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

     $nickn = trim($message[$i]);
     $nickname = urlencode($nickn);
    $url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=".$nickname . $ups;
    $page = getPage($url);

     $get = file_get_contents($url);
   // каков уровень в теге $content ?
    $content = $get;
    $pos = strpos($content, '&lvl=');
     $content = substr($content, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($content, '&tSrc=images');
     $content = substr($content, 0, $pos);
     $content = str_replace('&lvl=','', $content);
   // конец уровня

 // идет бой или нет ?
 $fight = $get;
    $pos = strpos($fight, '&fightId=');
     $fight = substr($fight, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($fight, '&farming=');
     $fight = substr($fight, 0, $pos);
     $fight = str_replace('&fightId=','', $fight);

  if ($fight) {
  $fightres = '<a href="http://w2.dwar.ru/fight_info.php?fight_id='.$fight.'" target="_blank">В БОЮ</a>';
} else {
  $fightres = 'СВОБОДЕН';
}
// конец боя





if (preg_match('/Магмары/',$page)) {

         echo '<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="prv[' . $nickn . ']"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> '. $message[$i] . ' [' . $content . ']<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a> :<span style="color: red;"><b>('.$fightres.')</b></span><br><br>';
    } else {
       echo '';
    }
}
  ?>
    <br /> Если никто не отобразился значит вы ни скопировали ни одного магмара)))  <br /> <br />
    При нажатии на кнопочку <button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="Копируется ник"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> мы копируем ник в буфер обмена в таком формате:<br /> prv[Ник жертвы]
<script src="http://trias.cf/wp-content/themes/new2/js/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
new Clipboard('.btn-clipboard');
</script>

<?php

} else { // дополнительно :)
}?>
```

Comment: Ой. Да никак пхп скрипт выполняеться в один поток. Можно разделить скрипт одну часть повесить на крон который будет парсить данные с определенным интервалом. А другой скрипт будет просто отображать полученую инфу

Comment: Просто видел статьи о многопоточности , но в с моими знаниями ) всё методом тыка... )) ничего не понял ) А на счет крона не сойдет , там сам вставляешь список , жмешь и оно передается , списки разные все время

Comment: А где можно написать такое ? что б это все отображалось быстро ?) какой язык ?) в чем ?)

Comment: Как то получить все ники разом

Comment: Да ники и так разом из бд берутся))) потом получается много ссылок по которым шарит скрипт вытягивая данные по каждому) и это занимает уйму времени